# Proof by Induction: Stuck

Tags: proof-writing, integers

I feel as if this should be really really easy but is my brain getting there...? No... 
So here it is:

**Prove by induction that if $b$ is an odd number and $n$ is a positive integer, then $b^n$ is also odd.** 
I'm thinking let $b=2a+1$ or something but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track...

Oh, and also here's the second part to my question: 
**Using the conclusion of the first part of this question, show that the equation $x^{19}+x+1=0$ has no solutions that are integers.**

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Couldn't you try showing that b = 2k+1 where k is an integer and showing that (2k+1)^n mod 2 cannot equal 0 because (2k+1)^n  = 1^n = 1 mod 2.

Comment: Use induction on n, not on b.

Comment: For the second part of the question could you try using the mean value theorem to prove it only has one root over the real numbers. Then use the intermediate value theorem to prove that root is in between (-1,0) meaning there wouldn't be any integer solutions.

Comment: @user262291 *Not* the way to go, clearly.

Answer (score 1):

$b = 2a + 1$ is a fine start.  Can you show that $b^2$ is odd?
Now suppose $b^n$ is odd.
Based on that assumption show that $b^{n+1}$ is odd.

that will prove the first part.

Part b.  Suppose x is even.
$x^{19} + x + 1$ is odd and hence not equal to 0.
Suppose x is odd.
$x^{19} + x + 1$ is odd and hence not equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $b$ is an odd number. Then $b^1=b$ which is odd. Assume that $b^n$ is odd and show that $b^{n+1}$ must also be odd. Then $b^{n+1}=b(b)^n$, which is an odd times an odd by our induction hypothesis. Thus $b^{n+1}$ is odd and $b^n$ will always be odd.

Doug M's proof for part b looks good to me.